# What is application of the basis of the image of a module?

Tags: modules, free-modules

Let us given a module homomorphism $h: M \to N$, where $M,N$ are $\mathbb Z_p$-module and $\mathbb Z_p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers.

> Assume that $\{u,v\}$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$-basis of the image $h(M)$. What can we get by utilizing this information ?

---

I want to know what would be the possible application once we know that $\{u,v\}$ of the image $h(M)$. Here $h(M)$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$-module of rank $2$.

- The value $h(m)$ for $m \in M$ is used in many important formulas in number theory. So because $\{u,v\}$ is basis of $h(M)$, we have $$h(m)= au+bv,$$ for some scalars $a,b \in \mathbb Z_p$. But still we don't know $a,b$. Is it practically possible to compute specific scalars $a,b$ here ?
- Suppose $M$ is a free $\mathbb Z_p$ with basis $\{x,y\}$, then $m=cx+dy$ for some scalars $c,d \in \mathbb Z_p$. Therefore, $$h(m)=h(cx+dy)=ch(x)+dh(y).$$

Can someone highlight in other situations where the "knowing the basis of the image of a module under the module homomorphism is important" ?

Comment: This seems too vague to really answer.  Is there some more specific context you're interested in?

Comment: @EricWofsey, yes there is something in the context. In my research article, I have calculated basis of  the image $h(M)$ of $M$. In my case M,N are special type of $\mathbb Z_p$-module and $h$ is special map. In have shown, $h(M)$ is $\mathbb Z_p$-module of rank $2$. The referee asked me to show some applications of the bases of $h(M)$ I have calculated. One thing I know that, the value $h(m)$ at every $m \in M$ is always used in very important formulas in number theory, for that special map $h$. So I thing the basis $\{u,v\}$ at least theoretically allows to compute $h(m)$ at $m \in M$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, is there other possible conclusion/application knowing the basis of $h(M)$ ?

Comment: You probably know why it is useful to have a basis for a vector space. Here it is just the same.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, yes I know given a basis of vector space we can generate the whole vector space and any vector can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements. In my case, any element, say $h(m)$ of $h(M)$ can be written as a linear combination $h(m)=a u+bv$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb Z_p$. My point is that, the value of such $h(m)$ is needed in many important formula in number theory. So theoretically it is possible to compute $h(m)$ once I have the basis, but practically we don't know the scalars $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, when $M,N$ are $R$-modules being $R$ a ring, if $u,v$ is a basis of $h(M)$ then there exist two elements, $x,y\in M$ such that $h(x)=u$ and $h(y)=v$.

Now, as you has said, you can compute $h$ for any element of the free submodule of $M$
$$
L=Rx\oplus Ry
$$

Now, what you have to wonder is:
$$
M=L\oplus Ker(h) ?
$$

Because in that case, you can consider that your map $h$ is "factored by a projection": given an element $m=\alpha x+\beta y+d$, you send $m$ to $\alpha x+\beta y$ and then apply $h$.

I don't know if this applies in your specific setup, but maybe it gives you a clue to continue searching.

Comment: I also thought something like that. It is true that $M \cong R^{\oplus 2} \oplus \text{ker}(h) \cong Rx \oplus Ry \oplus \text{ker}(h)$, so $M \cong L \oplus \text{Ker}(h)$. I think